How much better are the pink mini-turbos than the yellow mini-turbos?
I don't own a Switch, so I never really have had any experience with the pink (or purple) mini-turbo sparks in Mario Kart 8 Deluxe.
I know the mini-turbo (blue sparks) gives a little bit of a speed boost and the super-mini-turbo (yellow sparks) makes you almost as fast as someone using a Mushroom.
Comparing it with the mushroom, how much faster are the pink sparks? Does it work just like the mushroom, or did they slow down the yellow boost so the pink seems faster? (Also what does Nintendo call the pink sparks?)

This should be split into separate questions for Mario Kart 8 and Mario Kart Tour.

I'm just bring both games up because I know they have Ultra Mini-Turbos.

The Ultra Mini-Turbo may work differently between the two games. An answer for Mario Kart 8 won't necessarily apply to Mario Kart Tour.

That is true. OK, I'll edit this question and ask a this question for MK Tour.

According to a YouTube video uploaded by Nintendo:



it appears that all Mini Turbos have the same power, but last for a different amount of time.



Color
Turbo name
Duration (s)




Blue
Mini Turbo
0.621


Yellow
Super Mini Turbo
1.674


Pink/Purple
Ultra Mini Turbo
2.633



Unfortunately, I couldn't find any information on the Mushroom. It's possible it has the same power as the Mini Turbos but with a different duration. As to where it ranks in that table, or whether it lasts even longer than the Ultra Mini Turbo, I can't say.

Ultra Mini Turbos are more impressive than I thought. Thanks.
You don't have side by side video or multiplayer video you could make of Mushroom vs. Ultra Mini Turbo?

@Alex, sadly I don't have the time or capacity for that. I could post this video because I already knew it existed.

That's alright. This will help me out a lot for future references. Thanks Nolonar.
